# Live Data Value was never set

Tags: android, kotlin, testing

i'm new to kotlin android. I'm trying to learn testing, but get an error where it says live data value was never set, even when i use advanceUntilIdle.

Here is my repository

```
class UserRepository private constructor(
    private val userPreference: UserPreference,
    private val apiService: ApiService
) {
  
    private val _loginResponse = MutableLiveData<LoginResponse?>()
    val loginResponse: LiveData<LoginResponse?> = _loginResponse

    private val _errorLoginMessage = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val errorLoginMessage: LiveData<String?> = _errorLoginMessage

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        _showLoading.value = true
        val client = apiService.login(email, password)

        client.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>
            ) {
                _showLoading.value = false
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response : ${response.body()}")
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    _loginResponse.value = response.body()
                } else {
                    _errorLoginMessage.value = response.message()
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                _showLoading.value = false
                _errorLoginMessage.value = t.message
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and here is my viewmodel

```
class LoginViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val loginResponse: LiveData<LoginResponse?> = repository.loginResponse
    val errorMessage = repository.errorLoginMessage

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        repository.login(email, password)
    }
}
```

and here is my test

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {

    private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    private val context = RuntimeEnvironment.getApplication().applicationContext

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val userRepository = UserRepository.getInstance(
            UserPreference.getInstance(context.dataStore)
        )

        viewModel = LoginViewModel(
            userRepository
        )

        Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test Login Failed`() = runTest {
        viewModel.login("testWrongEmail@gmail.com", "testWrongPassword")
        advanceUntilIdle()
        val result = viewModel.loginResponse.getOrAwaitValue()
        Assert.assertEquals(true, result?.error)
        Assert.assertEquals("failed", result?.message)
    }
}
```

it works just fine when run, but not when testing. Why is that?

I'm trying to add InstantRuleExecutor, setting the main dispatcher, and add runTest. I also tried to change enqueue into execute but still no result

Comment: It looks a bit odd to me to launch a coroutine which does nothing except calling an asynchronous function, which at some point delivers its result through one of two `LiveData`s.  Couldn't your repository's `login` function make use of [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to suspend until one of the callbacks fire and then resume the coroutine with either a loginresponse or an exception?

Comment: Sorry, i don't really get what you mean here. I tried to remove the viewmodelscope part, but the live data also never set. I Update the code to the part where viewmodelscope is removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`advanceUntilIdle` executes pending **coroutines**. This is hinted at by the fact that it's part of the `kotlinx-coroutines-test` package.

`viewModel.login("testWrongEmail@gmail.com", "testWrongPassword")` calls `ViewModel.login()` calls `UserRepository.login()` which calls `client.enqueue()`. `client.enqueue()` is a callback based asynchronous function which uses Threads (a more traditional way of doing concurrency which predates coroutines). This means that `client.enqueue()` does not fire a coroutine.

What this means is that the `advanceUntilIdle()` call will return before `client.enqueue()` completes which causes the issue you are getting.

The fix is to change your `ViewModel.login()` implementation to use coroutines instead.

The easiest way to do this is to use `Call.execute()` instead of `enqueue()` to turn the network call into a synchronous call. Then you can use `runInterruptible` to convert a synchronous call into a cancelable coroutine call.

Putting it all together you get

```
    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        _showLoading.value = true

        // launch a new coroutine
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                // Use the IO dispatcher since this is a network call
                val response = runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    apiService.login(email, password).execute()
                }

                _showLoading.value = false
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response : ${response.body()}")
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    _loginResponse.value = response.body()
                } else {
                    _errorLoginMessage.value = response.message()
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _showLoading.value = false
                _errorLoginMessage.value = e.message
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```